# How to initialize a variable of an abstract class from a child class

Tags: kotlin

I have an abstract class:

```
inner abstract class Base {        
        fun Buscar(): Int {
            // Do something with a object called Q
        }
    }
```

And two secondary class that I need to initialize Q with certain class

```
    inner class BFS(): Base() {
        constructor(): this() {
            Q = Cola()
        }
            
    }

    inner class DFS(): Base() {
        constructor(): this() {
            Q = Pila()
        }        
    }
```

How can I do that?

--- EDIT ---
Pila() and Cola() are classes from an abstract class called Secuencia:

```
abstract class Secuencia<T> { ... }
public class Pila<T> : Secuencia<T>() { ... }
public class Cola<T> : Secuencia<T>() { ... }
```

Comment: How are `Q`, `Cola` and `Pila` declared? Please show a [mcve]. What is the error you get when you tried this code?

Comment: Cola and Pila are classes from an abstract class called Secuencia (i edited post). Q is a instance of Cola or Pila.I really don't know how to initialize a instance from a secondary class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make `Q` `abstract` and initialise it in your class, e.g.

```
sealed class Algo(val message: String)
class Cola : Algo("cola")
class Pila : Algo("pila")

abstract class Base {
    // all concrete classes need to define a value for 'q'
    abstract val q: Algo
    
    fun buscar(): Int {
        // you can reference q here since a concrete class will have initialised it
        println(q.message)
        return 1
    }

}

class BFS(): Base() {
    // since q is abstract it needs to be overridden in a concrete class
    override val q = Cola()
}

class DFS(): Base() {
    override val q = Pila()       
}

fun main() {
    BFS().buscar()
    DFS().buscar()
}

>> cola
>> pila
```